# How should this formula be interpreted?

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

$$\large\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{(i = 1)}^n A_i \right)= \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} {\sum_{1\leq i_1\lt\cdots\lt i_k\leq n} \mathbb P\left(A_{i_1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_k}\right)}\\$$

Can someone help me understand this formula?

Comment: If you would reveal what the "something weird" you got is, it would be a lot easier to provide you with relevant help.

Comment: You seem to understand the formula already: the minuses are to subtract the replicas.  That's all there is to it.  What's weird about the "something weird"?

Comment: I thought it was a general formula for a probability of a union, but when I chose n=3, and expanded the formula with that, it didn't seem to do that.

Comment: Maybe you didn't count well, this surely is a good formula

Comment: When k = 2 in the first sum and i_1 comes to i_2 in the second sum, the the second sum produces A_i_2 which has a negative sign because of (-1)^(2+1), but A_i_2 never repeats itself later (without intersection with another A_i_k), so in the final sum it stays negative. That cannot be. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the notation of the formula. Those $i_1,i_2,..,i_k$ are all possible groups of k subsets $A_i$, there are $n\choose k$ such groups for each k

Comment: $p(A_1)+p(A_2)+p(A_3)-(p(A_1A_2)+p(A_1A_3)+p(A_2A_3))+p(A_1A_2A_3)$ it cannot possibly be negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought it was a general formula for a probability of a union, but
>   when I chose n=3, and expanded the formula with that, it didn't seem
>   to do that.

For $n=3$ the formula is

$P(A_1 \cup A_2\cup U_3)$

$=P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3)-P(A_1 \cap A_2)-P(A_1 \cap A_3)-P(A_2 \cap A_3)+P(A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3)$

In the graph $A_1=A, A_2=B$ and $A_3=C$

[image]

**1)**

$A+B+C$: $e,g$ and $n$ are counted once. $f,k,m$ are counted twice. $h$ is counted three times.

**2)**

$-(A\cap B)$: $f$ and $h$ are subtracted.

$-(A\cap C)$:  $k$ and $h$ are subtracted

$-(B\cap C)$: $m$ and $h$ are subracted.

Summing up all sets (1&2): $e+g+n+ 2\cdot (f+k+m)+ 3\cdot h -f-h-k-h-m-h
=e+g+n+f+k+m$

**3)**

Adding $A\cap B\cap C: h$

$A\cup B\cup C=e+g+n+f+k+m+h$

Answer (score 1):

Let x be an element that belongs to k of the sets $A_i$, let that be sets $A_1,A_2...A_k$, you want to count it only once.

When you're adding single sets you count x k times, then when you subtract pairs you count x $k\choose 2$ times, and so on... until you count groups of k subsets $A_i$ when you count x once.

So number of times x was counted is $N_x=k-{k\choose 2}+{k\choose 3}-...\pm{k\choose k}=1-(1-1)^k=1$ so each element of the union is counted once.